# how to set state_use_accessors of Linux irq?

Tags: linux, interrupt, interrupt-handling, irq

`struct irq_data` has member of `state_use_accessors`, and in `linux/irq.h` there are some static function which use state_use_accessors to get state.

I have questions that:
1, when and where is the `state_use_accessors` value set?  I `grep` the source code, but not found.

2, the function used `state_use_accessors` is static, such as

```
211 static inline u32 irqd_get_trigger_type(struct irq_data *d)
212 {
213         return d->state_use_accessors & IRQD_TRIGGER_MASK;
214 }
```

can I use the implementation  in my own code?

Thank you~

Kind Regards
Bill Wang

Comment: Why do you need this `state_use_accessors`?

Comment: I want to get trigger type in irq hard handler, and gpio_get_value may sleep